# I received 15 downvotes today, to each one of my 15 answers, and all of them at 4.30 p.m. GMT

Tags: support, down-votes

No doubt there's a serial downvoter at large.
Could you, moderators, kindly reverse that?  And I'm sure most of us would appreciate it if such a member could be punished.

BTW, Where are the moderators here?  I've flagged for some unusual activity, more than once during the month of November, and received no answer.

Comment: Moderators do not have the power to reverse votes. You've raised exactly two flags. The first one complained about down votes (non-serial), and it was marked as "helpful" with a feedback comment that the DV were likely due to lack of references. The second one was to the effect of "I've given up on this site; how do you people expect it to work?" which is not the sort of thing conducive to one-on-one flag feedback. Here on Meta is the appropriate forum to raise such issues and receive feedback.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, serial downvoting should be reversed within 24 hours. Based on your profile it does seem that some serial downvoting has taken place, so hopefully the reversal will occur.

If in the next day, the reversal doesn't happen, you will want to use the [Contact us](https://health.stackexchange.com/contact) page to reach an SE employee because, unfortunately, the mods here can't reverse serial downvoting on our own.

For more info see [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) and [What should you do if you're serial downvoted & it isn't automatically reversed within 24 hours?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212332/what-should-you-do-if-youre-serial-downvoted-it-isnt-automatically-reversed)

Comment: Is that all the system does?   Isn't there any punishment for that kind of behavior?

Comment: Yes, but if we have a repeat offender, we may be able to manually review and suspend the user.

Comment: @michaelpri IMHO punishment should happen at the first serial downvotes. Simply because we don't know how many other serial downvotes they may have done before.

Comment: Why wait for a second time?   There are a different degrees of punishment, from temporary suspensions to account deletions.  Suspensions follow a prescribed progression: 0-day (warning), 7-day, 30-day, 365-day  The progressive series of suspension durations applies to all Stack Exchange sites.  The mods know it and it's within their power to apply some sort of punishment whenever they spot wrongdoings.  To simply overlook it because it's the first time you spot it, is to encourage potential scoundrels.

Comment: @Centaurus The system is set up to automatically reverse these votes and doesn't even alert the moderators. Even if a user points it out, the moderators have no way of confirming whether or not the "serial" voting was indeed "malicious" or whether a user was down voting content from several different users which they didn't like (perhaps legitimately). Only the community managers can see who voted for what question, and if we escalated it to them every time the system spotted serial voting the SE Team would be forever caught in chasing these things down.

Comment: @Susan   I regret to hear that.  It works differently in some SE sites where there seems to exist a closer relationship between the mods and the powers-that-be.

Comment: 1. "the moderators have no way of confirming whether or not the "serial" voting was indeed "malicious" or whether a user was down voting content from several different users which they didn't like (perhaps legitimately)"    2. "if we have a repeat offender, we may be able to manually review and suspend the user. From 1 by @Susan and 2 by michaelpri one can easily conclude there will never be any punishment. If the mods don't take the trouble to know who did it the first time and even if they know they can't say whether it was malicious or not, how can they punish whoever does it a second time?

Comment: I think this just indicates that the community team would need to be involved to confirm irregularities if they weren't caught by the system. We can certainly contact them for you if these don't get reversed automatically. Alternatively, Michael has given you a link to contact them yourself if you prefer.

Comment: @Susan Since it also happened to me, perhaps on the same day as Centarus, is there a serial serial down voter (I couldn't help myself with that phrase).  I don't know if it's someone targeting MDs. or just someone who didn't like our stuff, something random, or completely unrelated.  Is there a way to search how many people have had reputation added back from serial down votes? That might let us know if there is a more worrisome problem.

Comment: @AtlLED Such is not available to moderators, but I escalated the issue to the Community team to clarify voting issues, as noted in [an answer to your other question](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/a/658/165).